# How to make the bootstrapper installer show UI when uninstall by Add/Remove?

Tags: user-interface, wix, bootstrapper

How to make the installer can popup UI or dialog when unistalling by Add/Remove?

Right now the installer that is created by the Wix v3.8 bootstrapper only has one confirmation dialog to remove. How do I do? Please give me help, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you build a custom BA, you can show whatever UI you'd like on all cases. Uninstall is launched with a "/passive" switch which means to show very basic UI with the minimal questions. The standard BA provided in the WiX toolset (wixstdba) respects that and uninstalls with minimal UI. Thus, you'll need a custom BA that did something custom.

Creating a custom BA takes more work but does give you lots of control over the entire user experience.